# Socket.io + jquery for img src variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, socket.io

**EDIT: It was a minor problem, solved now. Thanks!**

I know there's a lot of answers for this, but none worked for me.
I want to put a image URL dynamically from the data socket.io gives

So, i have express.io running and working in a node.js server.

In the client part, i tried this:

```
io = io.connect()

io.emit('ready')

io.on('info', function(data) {
  $('#random').text(data.random)
  // tried to use text instead of attr too
  $('.image').attr('src', data.source)
  // just to have sure if it is working; it works
  alert(data.source)
})
```

And in the html part, this works:

```
<div id="random">[data shows up here]</div>
```

But the image part doesn't:

```
<img class="image"/>
```

Comment: How about adding `console.log( data.source )` and see what you get !

Comment: I used the alert for that, it indeed works.

Comment: Works how, what do you get ?

Comment: The URL I want to put on a <img> src.

Comment: And you alerted `data.source`, not `data.cover` as in your example ?

Comment: Oh, I just forgot to change the name there. Both are data.source now.

Comment: Then try logging `$('.image').length` and see that you get a number over `0`, if you do, I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: It gives me 0: `alert($('.image').length)`

Comment: Then there's no such element available in the DOM at that time

Comment: There is no problem in your client-side javascript part and since you receive correct data inside `#random`, there's no problem in sockets connection either. So the only problem that's left is `data.source`. Please post server-side code where you're sending data to connected clients.

Comment: data.source is working fine (as I said before, I tested it with a `alert`). I'm actually having problems with the jquery/html part.